# Managing lists and sublists with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to create a database arrangement for the following scenario:

Users of the site each have their own master list. This part is already being handled by one table that holds everyone's items, with a field that matches each user's unique idea.

Each user will also be able to create any number of sub lists that are made up of the items from their master list. The order of the items in these lists will be editable, as well as the ability to insert some global values at certain points. This is the part I am stuck on.

What would be the most efficient way to handle the sub lists? I've thought about creating a table of lists that are identified by user id and have a field of comma separated values that correspond to the items from the master list that the sub list is composed of, but I feel I would have a hard time keeping track of the item order that way.

I have tried to search for this, but I am having trouble finding a way to phrase what I am trying to do in a searchable way.

Also, if there are any recommendations for learning material that may help me come up with this answer on my own, I would love some recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a many-to-many table with an extra column.  You'd have user_id, item_from_master_list_id, and position.  That way you could select by user_id, and order by position.